# XSLT how to process nodes when you know only a part of their name?

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I have an xml:

```
<somenode />
<somenode />
...
<node120>
...
<node121>
...
<somenode />
```

I need to process all nodes that start with "node". Numbers in the end could be any. 
If it would be possible, I would use regex and write code like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="node\d+">
```

but as far as I know, regex is not available in XSLT 1.0
Is there a way to handle with it?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath 1.0 expression :**

```
*[starts-with(name(.),'node') and number(substring-after(name(), 'node'))]
```

**explanation :**

- `starts-with(name(.),"node")` : evaluates to `true` if current element name starts with `"node"`.
- `number(substring-after(name(), 'node'))` : evaluates to `true` if part of the element name after `"node"` convertible to a *non-zero number* (as noted by @michael.hor257k in the comment below)

Comment: This will fail with `<node0/>`. -- `number(x)` does **not** evaluate to true if `x` is "*convertible to number*". It evaluates to true if the result is neither positive or negative zero nor NaN.

Answer (score 1):

there is no regex in xslt 1.0, you could use 'starts-with' ?

```
<xsl:for-each select='*[starts-with(name(.),"node")]'>
```

Comment: I think this is not enough, the regex also checks if the `node` is followed with a number. Still, it is not a problem, it can be done with XSLT1.0.